# Detecting recent player with ahk

Tags: autohotkey, video-player

I am new to ahk
I want to know if there is a way to detect which player was recently used?
For example if I play a video on YouTube(Chrome), then pause it and play another video in PotPlayer. Finally resume the YouTube again.
This script should detect YouTube as the latest video player.

Appreciate any help!